# Jquery plugins conflict with each other

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html page where I use jquery.gridder.min.js and other one is classie.js
Problem is both when I include jquery.gridder.min.js the functionality of classie.js does not work. The input text does not take any text.
Please can anyone help me with this.

I tried using noConflict but it doesnt work.

```
var $k =   var $k = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Comment: any html/code to show how you are using the libraries? All the functionality that classie provides is there in jQuery like `addClass`, `removeClass`, `toggleClass`, `hasClass`, or is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: I commented the preventDefault() function in gridder.js which solved my problem.